# Piping to stdout and reading from stdout in one command

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I have a zip that I want to be able to pull out certain files and zip in a new file.

unzip -l myZip.zip

```
fileA.txt
fileB.mp3
fileC.gif
fileD.jpg
fileE.gif
fileF.gif
fileG.txt
```

I believe it should be possible to unzip any file that matches say *.gif and zip these files into another zip *on one line*.

I tried a few variations of the below:

`unzip myZip.zip > 1 < zip newZip.zip`

but none worked.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is that unzip -l prints length, date and size as as name and so you will need to format that before passing it to the unzip command and so:

```
zip newzip $(unzip -l Grabber.zip "*.gif" | awk '$4 ~ /^.*\.gif$/ { print $4 }')
```

Awk print all 4th space delimited fields that end in .gif (file paths)